# REST for Yaws: roll one's own solution or use Yaws + Webmachine?

Tags: rest, erlang, erlang-otp, yaws, webmachine

I was reading a couple of articles on how to use Yaws in a RESTful way, how [Webmachine maps HTTP semantics to resources](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/webmachine/webmachine/images/http-headers-status-v3.png) and all of them helped a lot to grasp the concept.

- [Example API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290224/rest-api-implementation-using-yaws) in Zack Kessin's Building Web Applications with Erlang
- Steve Vinoski's [RESTful Services with Erlang and Yaws](http://www.infoq.com/articles/vinoski-erlang-rest)
- Sheehy/Vinoski - [Developing RESTful Web Services with Webmachine](http://steve.vinoski.net/pdf/IC-Developing_RESTful_Web_Services_with_Webmachine.pdf)

This is the point where I got confused: it seems like that Webmachine as a good [REST toolkit](https://github.com/webmachine/webmachine/wiki/Overview) and Yaws as a mature web server would complement each other instead of writing a REST implementation each time but I had found no trace of these tools being used together. The only relevant google hits were [Steve Vinoski's twitter](https://twitter.com/stevevinoski/status/300727592993058816) and [his github experiment](https://github.com/vinoski/webmachine/tree/yaws).

I am fairly new to OTP (and Yaws, web development etc) and I might be missing something. Webmachine is a full OTP application, bundled with Mochiweb so my guess would be that it is an overkill but that's just a shot in the dark.

(I know Cowboy has its own REST implementation too but Yaws is more appealing to me and REST is not always a necessity of course.)

Comment: There's been little interest in my Webmachine + Yaws fork, so I never pushed to get the necessary changes into Webmachine master. It could still happen, though, given that discussion about it seems to be coming up more frequently these days.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know that I am on the right track. Basically you could extract the main Webmachine logic to use it with any server,  right? (I guess you already did it because your fork mentions Cowboy as well but I still need to get used to erlang/OTP)

Comment: Webmachine contains numerous assumptions about Mochiweb. My fork, which is out of date at the moment, removes all those assumptions and replaces them with a portability layer that hides the underlying web server.